# Create a DWORD Pointer from Offset

Tags: c++, memory, pointers, offset, dword

So if I want to read some information at the offset 00A2E63C (e.g.)...
and I need to have it as a DWORD,

how can I convert the "00A2E63C" String to a proper DWORD?

help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned long x = strtoul("00A2E63C", NULL, 16);
```

This would convert the string "00A2E63C" into unsigned long.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::stringstream hai;
// insert string into hai here
DWORD d;
hai >> d;
void* ptr = (void*)d;
// INVOKE HIDEOUSLY UNSAFE AND UNDEFINED BEHAVIOUR HERE
```

I don't actually remember if it's undefined. But it's almost certainly hideously unsafe.

Comment: You'll probably want to add `std::hex` in there somewhere.